# Core Data - Remove entity from model

Tags: cocoa, core-data, entity

I may be utterly stupid, but I can not find out how to remove an entity that I have created. There are only options for adding entities and adding attributes in the `.xcdatamodel`.

Comment: the delete key doesn't work? I use a windows keyboard via KVM and selecting the entity and hitting <DELETE> works for me..

Comment: What do you mean, Apple is intuitive!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key to delete entities.

Comment: Thanks. So many options for adding entities and whatnot. But for deleting the only option you have is using the backspace key :-P

Comment: Yeah, there are a few places where you can only use Backspace in Xcode. An other one is the snippet list.

Comment: <Slap my head> -- I was trying Command-Backspace, and it kept trying to delete the entire xcdatamodel.

Comment: save my time to figure out how to delete an entity physically from the model.

Comment: Having a bachelor degree and 1 year of developing experience and still i didn't know how to delete an entity   Thank you.

Comment: Still valid in March 2024

Answer (score 2):

just click on that entity and press **delete** button :P

Answer (score 1):

Use the Backspace key to delete entities.Than close and reopen xcode...

But first duplicate and save project. Sometimes it create errors( 50% of the time)